# Trabalhar com vários banco de dados a partir do mesmo modelo de classes

Tags: python, orm

sou novo em Python e estou precisando implementar uma solução que cada usuário do sistema deve ter um banco de dados separado, resumidamente o que eu preciso é algo como

```
db1 = Persistencia('mysql', 'usuario','minhasenha', '192.168.0.1','banco1')    
db2 = Persistencia('mysql', 'usuario','minhasenha', '192.168.0.1','banco2')    

#mapeia os models para o banco de dados
db1.mapeiaModels([Pessoa, Contato])
db2.mapeiaModels([Pessoa, Contato])

#atualiza a estrutura do banco de acordo com o mapeamento, 
#adiciona ou altera colunas NUNCA apaga colunas
db1.sync() 

pessoa = Pessoa()
pessoa.nome = 'RODRIGO'
pessoa.telefone = '88888888'

db1.save(pessoa) #salva no banco de dados 1
db2.save(pessoa) #salva no banco de dados 2
```

Eu preciso ter esse controle a nível de código, logicamente eu não quero desenvolver um ORM, quero apenas fazer um `wrapper` de um dos frameworks ORM já existente, eu dei uma olhada no Django, PyPone e o SQLAlchemy, mas não conseguir identificar como eu posso criar essa minha classe ai `Persistencia` usando por "debaixo dos panos" um desses ORM e que ele me desse essa flexibilidade, como disse, sou novo no python e não conheço bem esses frameworks, alguma dica?

Obs: Preciso usar no mesmo servidor porém em `databases` separados como mostrado no exemplo, no caso `banco1` e `banco2` e é crucial a atualização de esquema com o mínimo de esforço, ou seja, o framework que será utilizado deve ter essa "feature"

Comment: Especifique mais o seu problema. O que você tentou de fato?

Comment: O que eu quero é saber se alguns dos ORMs teria condições de criar várias conexões com diferentes banco de dados com a mesma estrutura de classe, pois no meu caso cada cliente do sistema eu preciso criar um banco de dados para ele, tudo isso de forma automática claro, o ORM tendo condições de fazer isso eu iria fazer essa classe ai apenas para facilitar o uso e por trás iria utilizar o ORM, eu não sabia se tinha como fazer nem como fazer, mas acabei de achar esse tutorial aqui [http://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/] e vi que tenho como fazer isso! obrigado!

Comment: não entendi o porque do -1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções de como fazer isso, se você usa [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) você pode usar os models dele próprio, caso contrário, o ORM mais popular para python é o [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Usando o SQLAlchemy você pode criar várias conexões:

```
engine1 = create_engine('sqlite:///example1.db')
engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///example2.db')
```

E aproveitar os mesmos models só tomando o cuidado de na hora que efetivar as querys com os models usar o *session* referente a conexão correta.

Comment: Olha, inicialmente pelo o comentário eu tinha conseguido com o SQLAlchemy mas depois eu troquei para o DJango mesmo e vi que ele pode fazer isso tranquilo, obrigado pela resposta, vou colocar como aceita, valeww!